# Visit your new home objectives not being completed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have purchased a house, but the objective to visit it does not complete when I enter the house. It is stuck in my quest log, which is rather annoying.

Objectives that may be afflicted with the same bug:

- Visit Breezehome, your new house
- Visit Proudspire Manor, your new house
- Visit Honeyside, your new house
- Visit Vlindrel Hall, your new house
- Visit Hjerim, your new house

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://bugzilla.darkcreations.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4937) introduced by the Unofficial Skyrim Patch. Disabling USKP will allow the objectives to complete as normal, but may cause permanent damage to your save; instead, use the following console command: `setobjectivecompleted housepurchase x 1`, where x is 10 for Breezehome, 20 for Proudspire Manor, 30 for Honeyside, 40 for Vlindrel Hall or 50 for Hjerim.